# jade iteration through dataset object from mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, jade4j

i'm building a bookstore app with expressjs and using mongodb to store data i have a database of books i want to display to my index.jade but i keep running into an infinite loop

```
extends layout

block content
    .content
        each book in books
            .book
                img(src="/images/dumbk.png", width="150px", height="200px")
                h4.book-title #{book.title}
                h6.book-dtls Price: #{book.price} SDG
                p.book-desc #{book.description}
                a.btn.btn-primary.view(href="/books/details/1") View Book
```

and this is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Book = require('../models/bookModel');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', /*ensureAuthenticated, */function(req, res, next) {
    Book.find({}, function (err, books) {
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        var model = {books: books}

       console.log(model);
       res.render('index', /*{books: books},*/ { title: 'Members' });
     });
});
```

after logging model it logged all the books in my database but it does not render them and keeps running an infinite loop when i tried to log a book title by using book.title in the jade file

```
-console.log(book.title)
result was undefined
```

so am sure that the error is in the loop and the formatting

when i log the model the output is

```
[ { _id: the id, title: "book title", author: "author", price: "10", description: "a book description", stock: "5", cover: "dumbk.png" } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use console.log in the jade file because this is supposed to be a client side script. Your "books" object is back at the server, your console.log will  be executed later when the client does it. Try this instead (although there are better ways):

```
extends layout

block content
    each book in books
        .book
            img(src="/images/dumbk.png", width="150px", height="200px")
            h4.book-title #{book.title}
            h6.book-dtls Price: #{book.price} SDG
            p.book-desc #{book.description}
            a.btn.btn-primary.view(href="/books/details/1") View Book
    script.
        const books = JSON.parse("!{JSON.stringify(books)}");
        console.log(books[0] && books[0].title);
```

**Update**: according to your comments, you didn't even want this, just to get your Jade file to render books. To do that, you should pass the books array to renderer options:

```
res.render('index', { title: 'Members', books });
```

Comment: do i use this formula to display them too ? because my problem isn't logging them its desplaying them

Comment: Well, no. This is just one way to pass your data (`books` variable in this case) to the frontend _JavaScript_. If your book.title is not rendering in that `h4.book-title`, then it's a different matter. Is that your problem?

Comment: it gave an error "cannot read property "length" of undefined"

Comment: yes my problem is that the preoberties in my database are not rendering in my frontend

Comment: Why do you have the books param commented then? Try this node code: `res.render('index', { title: 'Members', books });`

Comment: Thank you so very much you have saved a life :)